# Groovy scripting in AEM cq5

Tags: regex, groovy, aem

I have requirement of changing the entire h2 tags in the AEM website to sentence casing ( first letter Uppercasing ). As a solution, I am trying to run a groovy script with a regex expression to do the work. For this I am using AEM groovy console by city tech. Unfortunately, regex expression is giving me a syntax error as below

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 38: unexpected char: '\' @ line 38, column 22.
   def regexStr = "^(.*?\=\s*\w)(.*)$"
                        ^

1 error
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:309)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:359)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:137)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:162)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:912)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:574)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:550)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:527)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:279)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:258)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:613)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:625)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:652)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:643)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell$parse.call(Unknown Source)
at com.citytechinc.cq.groovyconsole.services.impl.DefaultGroovyConsoleService.runScript(DefaultGroovyConsoleService.groovy:84)
at com.citytechinc.cq.groovyconsole.services.GroovyConsoleService$runScript.call(Unknown Source)
at com.citytechinc.cq.groovyconsole.servlets.ScriptPostServlet.doPost(ScriptPostServlet.groovy:39)
at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:148)
at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:344)
at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:375)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:508)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:356)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:168)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:254)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:301)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:290)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:64)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:221)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at uk.co.ee.web.filters.impl.SegmentCookieFilter.doFilter(SegmentCookieFilter.java:148)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at uk.co.ee.web.filters.impl.FormSSLFilter.doFilter(FormSSLFilter.java:145)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:127)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:206)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:127)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:263)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.service(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:250)
at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.doFilter(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:321)
at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:340)
at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:383)
at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletHandlerImpl.process(ServletHandlerImpl.java:335)
at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anybody point out what is that I am missing or help me out with a better approach for doing the task. thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
def emailStr = "someone@someplace.com" 
def regexStr = "^(.*?\=\s*\w)(.*)$" 
if (emailStr.matches(regexStr)) { 
    // If we arrive here then the emailStr is a correctly formatted email string 
    println 'this is matching'
} else { 
    // If we arrive here then the email address is not correctly formatted and needs to be handled somehow. 
    println 'this is not matching' 
}
```

Comment: Are these h2 tags are part of a richtext content? Do you want to find them with a regexp and then replace the first letter with uppercase version?

Comment: no Michal. It will be just some property enwrapped in h2 tag. @opal - thanks for editing the question and making it clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check this [documentation](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html) regarding Groovy and regular expressions. Following seems to work fine:

```groovy
def emailStr = "someone@someplace.com" 
def regexStr = /^(.*?\=\s*\w)(.*)$/ 
if (emailStr.matches(regexStr)) { 
    // If we arrive here then the emailStr is a correctly formatted email string 
    println 'this is matching'
} else { 
    // If we arrive here then the email address is not correctly formatted and needs to be handled somehow. 
    println 'this is not matching' 
}
```

Regarding the capitalization of the first letter of a particular property, this script may be helpful:

```
getNode("/content/").recurse({ node -> 
    if (node.get("title") != null && someBetterCondition) {
        node.set("title", node.get("title").trim().capitalize())
    };
})
```

However, you should write a better condition, as your property name may not be so unique across repository. Checking resource type of a component should do. Also, remember to save changes after this snippet of code by calling `save()`.

Comment: My bad. I was trying to mark it as a string and do the matching. thank Mike. your answer works.